# Find maximum value from specific column and group by them after that

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
p_id | store |      createdat      | device  | deviceserial | application
------+-------+---------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:02:39 | android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:08:18 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:10:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:20:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 10:40:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 10:45:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 10:50:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 08:47:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 08:55:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 08:59:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 13:01:11 | IOS     | 6625839828   | app-b
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 13:15:11 | IOS     | 6625839828   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 12:03:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 12:09:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 12:12:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 15:15:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 15:20:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 10:25:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 10:35:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 16:39:11 | IOS     | 6625839828   | app-b
```

I want to group by this records by hourly.Then find the max events(event_counts) value of app-a and app-b from store z-10 and z-11 in one hour. In real there will be more stores and applications.I tried with this query:

```
select distinct on (application) 
    application,
    count(*) as event_count,
    date_trunc('hour', createdat) as hr,store
from devices  
group by application,hr, store
order by application, event_count desc
```

Thats my result:

```
application  | event_count |         hr             store
--------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------
 app-a       |           4 | 2020-09-02 08:00:00 |z10
 app-b       |           3 | 2020-09-02 10:00:00 |z10
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
application  | event_count |         hr             store
--------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------
 app-a       |           4 | 2020-09-02 08:00:00 |z10
 app-b       |           3 | 2020-09-02 10:00:00 |z10
 app-a       |           3 | 2020-09-02 08:00:00 |z11
 app-b       |           2 | 2020-09-02 13:00:00 |z11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the peak hour for each application/store tuple, you use `distinct on` like this:

```
select distinct on (application, store) 
    application, store,
    count(*) as event_count,
    date_trunc('hour', createdat) as hr
from mytable  
group by application, store, hr
order by application, store, event_count desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a731d526d2fa5046cbb255056eb773e3)**:

```
application | store | event_count | hr                 
:---------- | :---- | ----------: | :------------------
app-a       | z10   |           4 | 2020-09-02 08:00:00
app-a       | z11   |           3 | 2020-09-02 08:00:00
app-b       | z10   |           3 | 2020-09-02 10:00:00
app-b       | z11   |           2 | 2020-09-02 13:00:00
```

Comment: Its not giving me expected result,@GMB.I want maximum hourly event _count  per app and per store.